# Highcharts Zoom in Logarithmic Scale

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was toying around with the Logarithmic Scale in Highcharts.
Noticed that the zoom behaves in a weird manner when close to minValue.

The [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/G6ALa/) is a slightly modified example of the [original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-log-axis/) that Highcharts had for demonstrating a line chart over log scale.

Here is the code in full for a column chart that utilizes a log scale.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type:'column',
            zoomType:'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 1
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'logarithmic',
            minorTickInterval: 0.1
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
            pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
        },
        series: [{            
            data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512],
            pointStart: 1
        }]
    });
});
```

Try zooming between .1 and 1 and you'll see that everything disappears but the chart seems to have zoomed somewhere.

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minRange) parameter

```
yAxis: {
            type: 'logarithmic',
            minRange:0.1,
            minorTickInterval: 0.1
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G6ALa/1/

Comment: Thanks. I do see that this improves the experience; but you'll still notice the "blanking out" behavior if you, say, zoom between "0 & 1" for the column "10".

Comment: Also, I think I'll mark this answer as accepted. I just went through the documentation on min-range and it makes sense. I guess the next question is how I would be able to convey to the user that this zoom level doesn't exist as opposed to zooming into ether.

Comment: Try to adapt minRange parametrs on both axis.